# snpEff annotation and variant in a gene

Tags: gene, sequence-annotation, snpeff

I'm using snpEff to annotate genetic variants. However, the annotation often returns more than one annotation (see below for an example):

```
NZ_JAKVDJ010000001.1    119361  .   T   C   23.1481 .   DP=22;VDB=0.124119;SGB=-0.690438;RPB=0.369955;MQB=0.0631559;MQSB=0.000399184;BQB=1;MQ0F=0;AC=1;AN=1;DP4=0,5,12,5;MQ=5;ANN=C|synonymous_variant|LOW|oprB|gene-MMZ02_RS00620|transcript|TRANSCRIPT_gene-MMZ02_RS00620|protein_coding|1/1|c.444A>G|p.Leu148Leu|444/1359|444/1359|148/452||WARNING_TRANSCRIPT_NO_START_CODON,C|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|MMZ02_RS00610|gene-MMZ02_RS00610|transcript|TRANSCRIPT_gene-MMZ02_RS00610|protein_coding||c.-3612A>G|||||3612|,C|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|MMZ02_RS00615|gene-MMZ02_RS00615|transcript|TRANSCRIPT_gene-MMZ02_RS00615|protein_coding||c.-1069A>G|||||1069|,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|MMZ02_RS00625|gene-MMZ02_RS00625|transcript|TRANSCRIPT_gene-MMZ02_RS00625|protein_coding||c.*785A>G|||||785|,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|MMZ02_RS00630|gene-MMZ02_RS00630|transcript|TRANSCRIPT_gene-MMZ02_RS00630|protein_coding||c.*1063A>G|||||1063|,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|MMZ02_RS00635|gene-MMZ02_RS00635|transcript|TRANSCRIPT_gene-MMZ02_RS00635|protein_coding||c.*2025A>G|||||2025|,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|MMZ02_RS00640|gene-MMZ02_RS00640|transcript|TRANSCRIPT_gene-MMZ02_RS00640|protein_coding||c.*2876A>G|||||2876|,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|MMZ02_RS00645|gene-MMZ02_RS00645|transcript|TRANSCRIPT_gene-MMZ02_RS00645|protein_coding||c.*3698A>G|||||3698|,C|intragenic_variant|MODIFIER|gene-MMZ02_RS01495|null|gene_variant|null|||n.119361T>C||||||    GT:PL   1:50,0
```

However, now I wonder if the first annotation always refers to the observed variant (whose position is listed at the start of the line with the annotations an other quality parameters. Thus, if I got the annotation from the example above, can I always trust that the variant I'm looking at occurred in the gene oprB? Or will snpEff sometimes also give annotations where only the 2nd, 3rd, etc. annotation is directly related to the varying DNA position? If so, how can I know with certainty in which gene one variant appears?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.